# Integrate multiple AppHarbor apps with existing Logentries account

Tags: logging, appharbor, logentries

I have an existing [Logentries](https://logentries.com/) account that I already log application data to. I would now like to also log AppHarbor infrastructure layer data (load balancer, iis, etc). Basically exactly what you get when you add the [AppHarbor Logentries plugin](https://appharbor.com/addons/logentries).

The problem with using the plugin approach is it creates a whole new account in logentries for each app. Not exactly practical when you have multiple apps or an existing account.

I have also tried to manually add a log drain to my app following the logentries syslog format that I saw after adding the plugin:
`syslog://ahb1.api.logentries.com:10000`
but gave up when I realized there was no way to specify the existing logentries log token.

Is this possible on AppHarbor currently? Will it be possible in the future? I've successfully got multiple AppHarbor apps to integrate with an existing NewRelic account, so hoping its also possible with Logentries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make use of AppHarbors log drain, you need to create a new log in your existing Logentries account, except choose Plain TCP, UDP as the source. This will give you a port number to use with the log drain as like you mentioned the Token input can't be configured with manual drains. Then on AppHarbor, you would add this url for the drain:

`syslog://api.logentries.com:PORT`

where PORT is the port number you were given when creating the log. You can create as many of these logs in your Logentries account as you wish and thus point as many AppHarbor sources to the one account as you like. You can give me a shout at support@logentries.com also if you have anymore questions, or here of course if you would prefer to use SO.

Mark

Comment: Thanks Mark. I get it now, I didn't realize there was a log type that didn't utilize log tokens. So in this mode what provides authentication on your end of the log source? The port number and source IP pair? How does this play with AppHarbor's elastic scaling and changing IP addresses?

Comment: No problem. Thats exactly it, the Plain TCP input uses the source IP and port, you may notice that on the right hand side of the screen on Logentries when you're viewing each of your logs, it says appharbor:port, this usually displays an IP, but AppHarbor provides an endpoint that we periodically ping to retrieve a list of IP's to whitelist that we then know to be AppHarbors servers. Thanks, Mark